# Using ejabberd with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ejabberd, xmpp4r

I'm trying to create a chat component to add to an existing Rails web app (and perhaps optimize communication with clients along the way). The architecture I was thinking of is: when a user authenticates on Rails, create his/her Jabber credentials and set them in JS on page load. Use ejabberd to accept flash TCP or BOSH (probably using [jquery-bosh](https://github.com/ssoper/jquery-bosh)) connections from clients, connect Rails to ejabberd (as a regular client) using xmpp4r and look at messages from clients as they come. If they're app-specific messages, do the relevant action, if they're user-to-user messages, pass them to the appropriate user/group. At the same time, continue to use Thin/Apache to serve the regular webpages.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Does this architecture make sense or is there something in it that's not doable?
2. Besides the ejabberd documentation and xmpp4r documentation, which I'm currently going through, are there any other resources you could point me to that might be of interest?

Thank you.

Comment: hi, I am looking into something similar, were you able to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I ended up using Node.js, Socket.io, and Redis but the outcome didn't scale as well as I hoped.